# Creating a list from data within another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a list

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]*100
```

I now need to create another list  that will contain the first 8 prime number locations from within `a`.

I have tried these two lines of code and they didn't work

```
b=a[2:3:5:7:11:13:17:19]
a[2:3:5:7:11:13:17:19]=b
```

The output for list A is "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" so its the locations 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 out of that output

Comment: It's unclear to me what you expected from that code. You already know what the first 8 primes in the list will be, and where they are, why not just write `b = [1, 2, 
 6, 7, ...]`?

Comment: But `a` is just `[1,2,3,4,5]` repeated 100 times?

Comment: @hqkhan yes exactly... If you need first 8 prime numbers then Pi's answer is correct.. If you have some very specific (and a little strange requirement) then go for taurus05's answer.

Comment: i have edited the question]

Comment: Iterate over `a` using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate); check each value for *primeness*; if a value is prime, save the index; stop when you have enough.

Comment: his does not work i get a syntax error]

Answer (score 3):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]*100
indices = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
b  = []
for i in indices:
   b.append(a[i])
print(b)
```

You have to access each element individually. `b=a[2:3:5:7:11:13:17:19]` **is not valid syntatically in Python. Actually, this is not the way to access elements at particular indices.**

Pythonic way to do the same thing (It will reduce code length) using List Comprehension:

```
indices = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
b = [a[i] for i in indices]
```

Comment: This would be a standard use-case for a list comprehension as well. +1

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Yes it can be!

Comment: I have posted the answer. If it works for you, upvote it so that it can be helpful to others as well. You can also mark it as appropriate answer.

Comment: Things become so simple if you convert your final `a` array to numpy

Comment: Why use a sword, when a knife will suffice? @Bazingaa

Comment: Well that depends on the personal taste. I like vectorized approaches. For this small case, it might be an overkill but it is always good to have options

Comment: Don't copy and paste the code from stackoverflow. There can be mismanaged spaces in the indentatioin. Try to rewrite the code on your own and then see. It is so lame, it will work on any machine with python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this using list comprehension (beware the test_prime method is not optimized at all):

```
def test_prime(n):
    if (n==1):
        return False
    elif (n==2):
        return True;
    else:
        for x in range(2,n):
            if(n % x==0):
                return False
        return True



a=[1,2,3,4,5]*100
b = [item for item in range(len(a)) if test_prime(a[item])]
b = b[0:8]

print b
```

which outputs (*note Python counts from 0*, so the first element of an array is 0 and not 1):

```
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12]
```

Comment: you can run the for loop till `n//2` only for a more efficient code

Comment: Actually I am trying to think of a way to interrupt the list comprehension, but my Python skills are to bad

Comment: @AshuGrover Right, sorry was blinded with the other problem. Actually even to sqrt of n